# Close Modal in UI React on Cancel button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am following https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal to create a Modal form.

I want to close the Modal when click on the `Cancel` button. I am restricted not to use the shorthand method suggested in the link above. How should I write the handleClose() function in order to close the Modal form?

```
handleClose = () => {
   console.log("close")
}

render(){
    return(
      <Modal trigger={<Button>Upload</Button>}closeIcon>
      <Modal.Content>
        <p>Please upload a valid file.</p>
        <Form.Input
          name="upload"
          label=""
          type="file"
          onChange={e =>
            this.setState({file_data : e.target.files[0]})}
        >
        </Form.Input>

      </Modal.Content>
      <Modal.Actions>
        <Button onClick = {this.handleClose}>Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button positive onClick = {this.handleUpload}>Upload
        </Button>
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually solved it. I initialize a variable in state which `model_open : false` and then declare two function for it.

```
handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ model_open: true })
}

handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ model_open: false })
}
```

Then I just call these method based on use case.

```
render(){
  return(
    <Modal
    trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Upload</Button>}
    open={this.state.model_open}
    onClose={this.handleClose}
    closeIcon>
    <Modal.Content>
      <p>Please upload a valid file.</p>
      <Form.Input
        name="upload"
        label=""
        type="file"
        onChange={e =>
          this.setState({file_data : e.target.files[0]})}
      > 
      </Form.Input>

    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions>
      <Button onClick = {this.handleClose}>Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button positive onClick = {this.handleUpload}>Upload
      </Button>
    </Modal.Actions>
  </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice solution Mervyn, you could also use the onOpen callback on the modal itself so that you don't have to add a click event to the button. This is helpful if you want to reuse the modal in different circumunstances, and pass a trigger (for example, open from a primary button, open from a menu item, etc).